# Rails Globalize Gem + JSON Resources Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, json-api, globalize, jsonapi-resources

I have a project where I need to use internacionalization for table fields and to provide a jsonapi.
To accomplish this I'm using the [Globalize Gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) and the [JSON API Gem](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources).

This is the code for a simple model called category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :special_type }
end

class CategoryResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :name, :special_type
end
```

When making  a simple request as `/categories` the response is fine:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "categories",
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:3000/v1/categories/1"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "test",
        "special-type": "1"
      }
   },
  ...
  ]
}
```

But when trying to sort by name with `/categories?sort=name' I get an exception:

> "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column categories.name does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT \"categories\".* FROM \"categories\" ORDER BY \"categories...\n                                                         ^\n: SELECT \"categories\".* FROM \"categories\" ORDER BY \"categories\".\"name\" ASC"

as the column `name` is not in the table `categories` but on the table `category_translations`. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JSON API Gem`, however, in order to sort the `categories` by name, you have to do: `Category.includes(:translations).order('category_translations.name')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I know that's how you do when you want to order something through globalize. But the JSONAPI-Resources gem seems to be ignoring this when getting a request with a sort option.